# Bulk import from RDBMS to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, rdbms, sqoop

I have a 1petabyte of data stored in Oracle and i want to put this data in hadoop .What should be advisable approaches? is it advisable to use Sqoop? if not then what approach or tools should be used to do such bulk loads

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop is a good option although I'm not sure if it supports bulk operations (as opposed to JDBC select query) with Oracle.

The problem is that Sqoop will try to do this as a single operation (although perhaps with multiple processes), and with this amount of data, you might want to do the import more piecemeal and fault tolerant.

What do you intend to do with the data afterwards? What format do you want to store the data in? Sqoop has other advantages like importing directly into Hive tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does support bulk operations that can be used as

```
  sqoop import --connnect <connect-str> --table foo --direct --target-dir /dest

  --direct flag controls the bulk behaviour
```

however for your use case you can use you can take use of --incremental imports to load that huge table incrementally

a quick look at sqoop user guide will get you running

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html